# Performance with IPEX

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, linear-regression, intel-pytorch

I tried linear regression & gradient descent in PyTorch. (https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/08/linear-regression-and-gradient-descent-in-pytorch/)

I've imported Ipex with the following command:

```
import intel_pytorch_extension as ipex
```

How can I convert the model to ipex? And how can I check that the performance has improved? Any help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing IPEX, use the below command while defining a model:

```
def model(X, IPEX=True):
return X @ w.t() + b
```

We have verified the code from the link you shared. You could replace `model(X)` with `model(X, IPEX=True)`

Performance with IPEX has improved drastically. Without IPEX, we could see some difference between Actual Target values & Model Predictions. Where as, with IPEX values has no difference.